# SwiftUI MacOS menu bar app TextField selectable and editable on launch, unselectable after minimizing and reopening

Tags: swift, swiftui

Working on my first Swift MacOS app, and for some reason the TextField is selectable and editable on first launch, but if the app is minimized and reopened, for some reason i'm unable to edit the field.

I hope someone has any recommendations on what to do.

```swift
var body: some View {
    VStack{
        WrappingHStack(alignment: .center, horizontalSpacing: 5, verticalSpacing: 5) {
            ForEach(listOfColors) { element in
                Button("") {
                    let pasteboard = NSPasteboard.general
                    pasteboard.declareTypes([.string], owner: nil)
                    pasteboard.setString("#" + element.paletteColors, forType: .string)
                    text = element.paletteColors
                    selectedIndex = element.indexVal
                }
                .clipShape(Circle())
                .frame(width: 25, height: 25)
                .background(Color(hex: element.paletteColors))
                .foregroundColor(Color(hex: element.paletteColors))
                .cornerRadius(33)
                .mask(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 90))
            }
        }
        .offset(y: 15)
        TextField("Text", text: $text)
            .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
            .padding()
            .onSubmit {
                listOfColors[selectedIndex] = PalletteColors(paletteColors: text, indexVal: selectedIndex)
            }
    }
}
```